# Read The Docs not updating

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

Read The Docs seems to be stuck on an old version of my docs and whatever I do in won't update. I even tried deleting the project from Read The Docs completely and reimporting the github repo - it still shows the old version. The builds show as successful.

To test this, I've changed a bit of text on the README.rst. It won't update. I've tried searching through all my project files for the old text, which is showing in the Read The Docs site - it doesn't exist in my files anywhere anymore so where is Read The Docs even getting it from?

It isn't my cache or anything either. I've cleared the cache, loaded the page on Private windows, different browsers and even a different computer and still I get the old docs.

Any ideas? I really have no idea what to try.

Comment: Please provide the project URL, and if you have some spare time, complete your question with a screenshot of what do you see online, and what do you see locally

Answer (score 3):

It can take a while (an hour or two) for the change to propagate to the website. Probably some caching being done by Cloudfare or something.

You can check the latest changes by clicking in the bottom left hand corner of the Documentation webpage and Downloading the html version - that seems to propagate immediately, probably it is a direct download from Read The Docs' servers.